# issue with installing open jdk in ubuntu natty

Tags: ubuntu, java

I am having this issue:

```
herlamba@domU-12-31-39-01-F2-1D:~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b22-1.10.4-0ubuntu1~11.04.1) ...
^C
^C
```

and it is just basically stuck in there. What should I do? I am using putty. Doing a control+z gets me out of this, but doesn't stop the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/natty/+source/linux/+bug/634487
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-on-ec2/+bug/310898

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest downloading and installing the oracle-java.bin  from Oracle   , set it to executable, run it , and then forget openJdk until you figure it out later.